# when create new project ssl peer shut down incorrectly in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

when create new project in android studio show me this error

---

### **ssl peer shut down incorrectly
remote host terminated the handshake**

I lot of looking about appropriate solution for this problem but i never find solution.
note: recently this problem occurred may when update android studio to 4.2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ4S4.png)